# Deleted comment

Tags: discussion, comments

My comment got deleted in the topic [Aspiring scientist](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70808/2451). It got deleted - fine. But I don't see who did it? Is it normal here, is it norm? I would like to be aware of moderators who do that without leaving a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Comments are ephermal, in general they can be deleted without explanation.

In this case, the link was possibly non mainstrean and had been flagged (we disallow non mainstream physics here), and besides it had no potential of improving the post.

Please only use comments to point out mistakes, ask for clarification, or suggest improvements.

Comment: Either way, I cleared out the rest of the discussion and left a comment to that effect. Note that this does not indicate that moderators have to explain deleted comments every time.

Comment: So basically moderator determines if book is a maintstream? How do you detect mainstreamity? Basically you personally judge it?! Or?. Only undisputedly mainstream books are encyclopedias and university books and even they have mistakes. Im curious to find out your algorithm. If my line of arguments is correct you should put in FAQ that this site does not PRETEND to be objective and is only reflection of personal opinions of its moderators. Who in this case should be visible publicly with their names. That we can understand who is who.

Comment: And secondly comments are comments you can not judge which information they bare - useful or not. If they are not important get rid of them on whole website.

Comment: To be absolutely precise i would like to know who determined that motionmountain.net is not a mainstream book?

Comment: @AsphirDom No. We [do define what is non mainstream](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site), however, that doesn't apply to comments. Comments can be deleted regardless of content -- if there are reasonable objections to a comment I may delete without checking the validity. I repeat, comments are ephermal. If this discussion was about a _post_, then yes, we would apply objective guidelines to delete.

Comment: @AsphirDom Sorry, we don't reveal details of who flagged what

Comment: @AsphirDom I wouldn't mind deleting all comments. However, in general I leave comments alone unless there's a long discussion or someone is objecting to them. The comments feature is useful, but its purpose is not to be permanent.

Comment: So comment was deleted due to flag? Funny. Some people actually went to investigate that book like anna v. The question was far from obvious.

Comment: OK situation is clear. Basically according to your definition of mainstream every community created book or effort (wikipedia alike) which is NOT published (wikipedia is NOT published in journal or publishing house) is NOT a mainstream :) Wikipedia on physics is not mainstream we got it :)

Comment: @AsphirDom The comments section is not appropriate for that discussion. If you/anna wish I can recover the deleted text and present it in a chatroom for further discussion. Again, it wasn't deleted because I "knew" it was non mainstream. The deletion of that comment does not in any way represent the definition of non mainstream physics here.